# cordova views from plugins are not visible

Tags: ios, cordova, dialog, cordova-plugins

we have a cordova app, started about 3 years ago.

the app was working without problems on iOS <= 8.

now randomly views created in plugins (even official ones from cordova team) are not displayed anymore. still on iOS8.

for example:

```
// Show the confirmation dialog
navigator.notification.confirm(
    "Are you sure you want to logout?",
    onConfirm,
    "Logout",
    ['OK','Cancel']
);
```

so very simple, pretty standard code.

the problem is also with other plugins.

Cordova version for ios 3.7.0
and org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.6.

the views or alerts are not shown in the app.
but if you double tap the Home HW button, you can see the view in the app screenshot.

sometimes when you get back in the app it is visible, sometimes not.

did anybody experience this, any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: Can you give more details about this? there is a know issue that looks like this, but not sure if it's the same

Comment: @jcesarmobile i am not sure what else to say :) this is pretty much what happens. in one of the plugins we use for listpickers we have fixed this by adding the view as a child of the webview, rather then its sibling. what is the known issue you mentioned?

Comment: the known issue is that you can't show a cordova dialog over a native view (in app browser plugin or any other plugin that display a native view controller)

Comment: no it is not that, it is the normal webview. but the funny thing is that it worked for years. the only think is that we updated the devices from ios8.x to ios8.4

Comment: so, it's random? sometimes it shows and others doesn't show?

Comment: yes its random, but some plugins work, some don't. and if at one place it does not work, then it always does not work there. also the same works on another device